# Sharepoint Date and Time Field limitation

Tags: sharepoint

I created a Date and Time column in a Sharepoint list called EventDate. According to Microsoft documentation the Date and Time column maps to the System.DateTime type.

Now I'm seeing an error message when I try to insert the following date into that column:

Date: 1/1/1800

Error message: 
"Invalid date/time value.
A date/time field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again."

I also tried to use set DateTime.MinValue and I receive the same error message. But if I insert a more recent date like 1/1/1900 it works fine.

Does Sharepoint have a limitation of the minimum value of a Date and Time field?

Answer (score 12):

I found out that if you try to insert the value 1/1/1800 in a Sharepoint Date and Time field manually (using Sharepoint forms) you receive this error:

"You must specify a valid date within the range of 1/1/1900 and 12/31/8900."

Therefore, Sharepoint only accepts values between 1/1/1900 and 12/31/8900.

Comment: Why do you want to add that date? If you really need a date before 1900, you could use a Single line of Text field.

Comment: Very nice answer.  It would be even better without the last line.

Comment: So does it mean SharePoint will stop working after year 8900?

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov If human kind still uses SharePoint then they deserve to be extinct in 8899

Answer (score 4):

There is no obvious reason as to why SharePoint limits the storage of the datetime datatype as it does now.

In SQL Server, the smalldatetime columns allows date in the range from 1/1/1900 - 6/6/2079 and the datetime columns are ranged 1/1/1753 - 12/31/9999

So there's no range from 1/1/1900 - 12/31/8900 and I haven't got the slightest idea why the limitation exists.

To make things even worse: SQL SErver 2008 has a smalldatetime2 and datetime2 type (the really just added a 2 to the name :/) wich allows any date (1/1/0000 - 12/31/9999) but even SharePoint 2010 on a SQL 2008 has the same limit

And Kit: using a single line of text is a very poor substitu, as there is no way to validate the values entered by the user

Comment: I also found that Single Line of text is not a great solution, I attempted to compare dates (converted to dates) and had issues with locale so was unable to ever satisfy my conditions

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a custom field to store the datetime value. 
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg132914.aspx

Comment: you could also have an event handler that validates that the string is a valid date time

Comment: @David The lack of ability to compare dates is a significant loss by itself. it makes no sense why Microsoft wouldn't map the field type back to SQL's built in capabilities.